# Shrinking QDialog With Function Call

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, runtime

I have a dialogue that is created and managed by the central application. The dialogue generates widgets at runtime and has a member function to restore the dialogue to its default arrangement, I.e. button box at the top and a single widget on the bottom. This restore function is called while the dialogue is hidden. I can get the extra widgets out of the dialogue, but I cannot get the dialogue itself to shrink to it's original size. Here is the code I'm using, names have been changed to be generic.

```
void Dialogue::restore()
{
    const short RESTORE_WIDTH = 800;
    const short RESTORE_HEIGHT = 200;
    QRect newGeometry(frameGeometry());

    // Remove all old origins
    foreach(RuntimeWidget* child, findChildren< RuntimeWidget* >())
        child->deleteLater();

    // Restore widget to default state
    newGeometry.setWidth(RESTORE_WIDTH);
    newGeometry.setHeight(RESTORE_HEIGHT);
    setGeometry(newGeometry);
    updateGeometry();
    addRuntimeWidget();
}

void Dialogue::addRuntimeWidget()
{
    RuntimeWidget* pWidget(new RuntimeWidget());

    vbxlytDialogue->addWidget(pWidget);
    adjustSize();
    adjustPosition(this);
    pWidget->setFocus(Qt::OtherFocusReason);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing there's a problem with your use of `deleteLater` here. The child widgets will only get deleted once you go back to the main event loop, and that will only happen *after* `restore()` is finished (i.e. after you've called `adjustSize`).

Have you tried removing the child widgets from whatever layout they're in before calling `deleteLater()`?

```
foreach(RuntimeWidget* child, findChildren< RuntimeWidget* >()) {
  vbxlytDialogue->removeWidget(child);
  child->deleteLater();
}
```

(Or something to that effect - I'm just guessing about the type of `vbxlytDialogue`.)

Comment: I have not, giving it a try now.

Comment: Worked great, except now the next call to the add, doesn't do a great job of resizing to fit the new widget. It's the next call after the first call that parent widget is actually adjusted to fit the new widgets.